# Response.Redirect cannot be called in a Page callback without redirects

Tags: asp.net, redirect

I have been getting this error on the production site and I had already read the other posts regarding this error, however I wasn't able to replicate it without putting redirects on my code

Can someone else tell me how to replicate this? I'm pretty sure that I don't have any redirects on my callback function.

Comment: Do you have a `Response.Redirect` _anywhere_ in your code? Like maybe in global.asax? Because maybe your callback is triggering some other piece of code that has a `Response.Redirect`. Like maybe `Application_Error`?

Comment: there are none sir, neither in the page itself nor in the global.asax

Comment: I think you'd better post some code. Preferably you would post a small example that reproduces the problem. If you can't create such an example, then post the _relevant_ code. For example, show the code related to ASP.NET stuff, but we don't need to see your business logic.